# How can i speed up a group by query that already uses indexes?

Tags: mysql

We have a MyISAM table with approximately 75 milion rows that has 5 columns:

```
id (int), 
user_id(int), 
page_id (int), 
type (enum with 6 strings)
date_created(datetime).
```

We have a primary index on the ID column, a unique index (user_id, page_id, date_created) AND a composite index (page_id, date_created)

The problem is that the query below takes up to 90 seconds to complete

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE user_id, count(id) nr 
FROM `table` 
WHERE `page_id`=301 
and `date_created` BETWEEN '2012-01-03' AND '2012-02-03 23:59:59' 
AND page_id<>user_id 
group by `user_id`
```

This is the explain of this query

```
+----+-------------+----------------------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table                      | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows   | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+----------------------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | table                      | range | page_id       | page_id | 12      | NULL | 520024 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
+----+-------------+----------------------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
```

**EDIT:**
At the suggestion of ypercube I tried adding a new index (page_id, user_id, date_created). However mysql does not use it bu default so i had to suggest it to the query optimizer. Here is the new query and the explain:

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE user_id, count(*) nr FROM `table` USE INDEX (usridexp) WHERE `page_id`=301 and `date_created` BETWEEN '2012-01-03' AND '2012-02-03 23:59:59' AND page_id<>user_id group by `user_id` ORDER BY NULL


    +----+-------------+----------------------------+------+---------------+----------+---------+-------+---------+--------------------------+
    | id | select_type | table                      | type | possible_keys | key      | key_len | ref   | rows    | Extra                    |
    +----+-------------+----------------------------+------+---------------+----------+---------+-------+---------+--------------------------+
    |  1 | SIMPLE      | table                      | ref  | usridexp      | usridexp | 4       | const | 3943444 | Using where; Using index |
    +----+-------------+----------------------------+------+---------------+----------+---------+-------+---------+--------------------------+
```

Comment: What is this strange `page_id <> user_id` condition for?

Comment: You can change the `count(id) nr` to `COUNT(*) nr`. It will slightly improve performance.

Comment: @ypercube the table stores interactions between users and pages, but pages can also interact with themselves. With that query i wish to see how many times each user interacted with the page except the page itself. I've removed it without seeeing any improvements. The COUNT(*) seems to improve performance a bit but from what i've seen only on pages with fewer entries in range. Thanks!

Comment: Other things you may want to check is the buffer settings. If the data can be held in memory (for the group-sort), without the temp table hitting the disk, it will help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Some changes that may improve the query:

- Change `COUNT(id)` to `COUNT(*)`. Since `id` is (I guess) the PRIMARY KEY and `NOT NULL`, the results will be identical.
- Add an `ORDER BY NULL` after ther `GROUP BY` clause. In MySQL, a group by operation also sorts the results, unless you specify other wise.
- The `(page_id, date_created)` is probably the best index that MySQL can use for this query but you could also try `(page_id, user_id, date_created)` (can you also post the EXPLAIN if you add this index?)

---

Another thing not related to the performance of this query:

If your `(user_id, page_id, date_created)` is `UNIQUE` and the `id` is auto generated (and not used for anything else but as a Primary Key), you can make it the `PRIMARY KEY` and drop the `id` column. One less index and 4 bytes less per row.

Comment: Thanks! the index you suggested speeds things up a lot. I updated the question with the explain you required. By forcing the index I managed to get it done under 0,1 seconds and without forcing it just under 1s.  Do you think it is going to affect our INSERT times if we leave both indexes? We run 3 inserts once per day that SELECT data from 3 tables.

Comment: Having many indices can affect Insert/Delete/Update statements performance. Keep the indices you need for your queries/statements and test if it affects the massive inserts unacceptably.

Comment: COUNT(1) would probably be better than count(*)

Comment: @JeffK not really. They should produce identical plans.

Answer (score 0):

1) It depends on your data - but you should have multiple indexes available to allow MySQL to choose the best one. e.g. if the table had an index on page_id it wouldn't be scanning so many rows.

2) There is a way of optimising date searches. I haven't actually implemented this myself yet, but have a similar problem that I have thought about quite a bit.

Basically you are looking up data by day - but date compares are really slow. What you could do is create another table that stores earliest and latest ID from table for each day. That table would need to be populated at the end of each day.

After that you could break your query into two parts:

i) Find the IDs to search y running two queries:
select earliestID from idCacheTable where date = '2012-01-03';
select latestID from idCacheTable where date = '2012-02-03';

ii) You can then search directly on the primary key of the table, without doing a date compare on each row, which would be waaaaaay faster.

SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE user_id, count(id) nr 
FROM `table` 
WHERE `page_id`=301 
and (id >= earliestID and id <= latestID)
AND page_id<>user_id 
group by `user_id`;

The exact solution to your problem will depend on what your data looks like though, rather than one of those two things always being correct.

Comment: i don't think that the problem is an index now. Basically mysql uses both the page_id and the date as index. I know this because before we didn't have a composite index and the number of rows returned would be around 4 milion, and also by looking at the key length you can see it uses both fields. The query is pretty fast for a table this big on pages with few entries in the date range.

Comment: Ah, sorry missed that it was already using an index on page_id. "The query is pretty fast for a table this big on pages with few entries in the date range." Yes, but depending on your data, you can probably examine much fewer rows, using a much faster compare than date, if you know what the earliest primary key id and latest primary key id of 'table' could be.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds odd, but try to add JOIN statement:

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE user_id, count(id) nr
FROM `table` t
JOIN `table` t2 ON t.`user_id`= t2.`user_id`
WHERE t.`page_id`=301
and t.`date_created` BETWEEN '2012-01-03' AND '2012-02-03 23:59:59'
AND t.`page_id`<>t.`user_id`
group by t.`user_id`
```

For similar problem, I got that query execute 20 times faster (3-4s instead 60+). JOIN statement does not perform anything smart - seems that speedup is fully to internal MySql implementation (Tested on MySql 5.1., table have rare user_id duplicates).